# Getting View size inside a BaseAdapter.getView()

Tags: android

I have an activity wich contains a ListView, the list is a thumbnail on the left and some text on the right, pretty much like a contact list.
[image] 
The thing is, the thumbnail is loading from an absolute path from the sdcard, and each image size is about 5mb. For avoiding running out of memory I created the classes in this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap) which loads only a scaled version of the images and doesn't take a lot of memory. 
Well, what's the problem? Since, I have to pass the width and the height (in px) that I want the image to be resized, but for differente devices I would have a problem setting absolute values. So, I just tried passing the view through args, and just manipulate it in my class to get the width and height, nice eh? Ok, but it didn't work, since the thumbnail hasn't been draw yeat (i guesss), I can't take his size values. 
How can I get the size inside the method getView() from my lisview adapter?

```
/** short passage of getView() method */
ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_thumb);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapAdjusted.decodeSampleBitmap("/sdcardpath/", 
            image); // "image" is the view passed by args
image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Here's the problem:

```
public static decodeSimpleBitmap(String path, View view){
    /** unworth previous code */
    int width = view.getWidth(); // always give zero, getMeasuredWidth() too
    int height = view.getHeight(); // always give zero
    // options is BitmapFactory.Options class, declared before that do the magic
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why are you using px instead of dip? If you pass the dip value (px x density of the screen) the thumbnail will looks at the same way on all devices